# USE of Timestamp or Rowversion to catch updates during ETL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

My datawarehouse ETL retrieves records from our HIS that uses a date range in the WHERE clause.  The concern is that a record may be inserted or updated within the date range but not picked up by the SELECT.  How could I use rowversion or timestamp to ensure my ETL picks up those changes?  What would that code look like?

SSIS SQL Task pseudo code:
      select * from HIS.Patient.PatientAddress 
     where editdate> @LogFileLastETLDate and editdate < MAX(HIS.Patient.editdate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do much the same thing in one of my projects:

1. Use an identity column (ID) on the source table
2. Check the max ID on
3. the target Check max ID on the source
4. Transfer from source where ID
5. between MaxTarget and MaxSource